# Distinguishing between objects fetched from the in-memory Managed Object Context and the Persistent Store

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data

In an iOS app, I am creating `NSManagedObject` subclass objects using a framework that parses JSON objects and then inserts them into an `NSManagedObjectContext`. However, I want to distinguish between those newly created objects and ones that have already been saved into the persistent store. That's because I may need to update or overwrite some of the objects in the store. When I execute an `NSFetchRequest`, it simply returns all of the registered objects, both objects fetched from the store, and the ones I've created locally, in-memory. How would I be able to distinguish between the two types of objects?

Comment: Why not delay inserting the new object until you have identified whether a matching object exists? Alternatively you could use multiple managed object contexts but that seems like an overly complex solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, the framework parses JSON and requires passing the newly created managed object into a context. I suppose I can get around this by having two contexts, one for object creation and the other for reading from a persistent store, but that seems overcomplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell if a managed object has been saved by looking at its object ID. Check `myObject.objectID.isTemporaryID`, which will be `true` until you first save the object and `false` from then on.

However as @Paulw11 alludes to in a comment, in this case it's generally better to find out if you already have a local object *before* creating a new one. That avoids the issue of having duplicates. You can either update values on the existing object or delete it and replace it.